# Pagination in Rails 3 with Kaminari always "destroys" one part of the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, routes, url-routing, kaminari

I'm using a Rails 3 App with Kaminari for Pagination. Because of my language, SEO and friendly URLs I want to change my URLs looks like. But it seems I have to decide between friendly pagination links and or displaying the correct method names. But first things first:

I have a model, which is called "pages" and contains some pages which can't be applied to only one model or don't contain any model. The following is a snippet of my "routes.rb":

```
match'/neugikeiten', :to => 'pages#neuigkeiten'

scope(:path_names => { :new => "neu", :edit => "bearbeiten", :delete => "loeschen", :index => "index", :page => "seite" }) do
  resources :news, :path => "neuigkeiten"
end
```

As you can see, I match every page from pages to a single name and match all my other models and methods (I only used one as example) with scope. All of this works just fine. But now I have to add the Kaminare routes, for which the route looks like this:

```
resources :pages do
  get 'seite/:page', :action => :neuigkeiten, :on => :collection
end
```

So, basically what I want to get is an URL like this:

```
/neuigkeiten/seite/2
```

The 2 is just an example and seite is the german word for page. But what i do get, is this:

```
/pages/seite/2
```

So, I get the model name, instead of the name I defined for this single page. I already tried switching the different codes but either I just have the original model name in the URL or I don't get nice URLs for pagination, which look like this:

```
/neuigkeiten?page=2
```

And if I try to match the pages without the resource like this:

```
match'/tagebuch/seite/:page', :to => 'pages#tagebuch', :on => :collection
```

I get the following error.

```
can't use collection outside resources scope
```

It seems to me that there should be another method to do this, because I can't be the only one having this kind of problem.

I'm glad for any help!

Comment: just a suggestion, if you stick to conventions it will make your life easier. you could do all routing and object naming in plain english, and manage some locales within the app

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I want the routes in german language. And even if I did want them in the english language, I would still have the problem, that rails gives me the model name and not the name of the page in the URL. So it's not only a matter of language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is interested in an solution, I found one myself. It's not perfect, but it works.

I had to install an extra gem for the localisation called "i18n_routing". Then in my routes.rb I did:

```
localized do
  resources :news, :path => "neuigkeiten" do
    get 'seite/:page', :action => :index, :on => :collection
  end
end
```

The rest is done in the localized language file (en.yml).